# How to use element with object property like element.myobj.prop

Tags: javascript, oop, object, object-properties

If I declare a object like

```
var obj =function(element){
return{
wide:element.clientWidth
}}
```

I must declare it like

```
var fdiv=new obj(document.etc.etc.);
```

and call like

```
fdiv.wide;
```

But this is quite limiting my code. I must declare new obj for each element.
My question is how i can set element name dynamic in order to be able to use like `nodeI_want.obj.wide` or `obj.nodeI_want.wide` or anything like this to use my property with dynamically given node.
note:clientWidth prop. is just an example to clarify it will be replaced in my code with my own properties.

Comment: I don't get it, why would `wide` be a property of the element, and why would you need it if it's just the same as the `clientWidth` property?

Comment: this is just an example it could be anything

Comment: What you've posted is invalid code, and it makes no sense, at least not to me ?

Comment: Does this help -> http://jsfiddle.net/hpanpxe3/

Comment: because it is not supposed to work the aim here to understand the logic behind the system. @adeneo

Comment: this is what i want o avoid it is not dynamic for each element i must create a new object

Comment: This question needs to be reworded. It sounds like you are trying to ask how to dynamically generate objects? Or am i misinterpreting what you are trying to ask?

Comment: Well, you could at least bother to write the object correctly,  as in `return {key : 'value'}`

Comment: the answer below explains the question @HatterisMad

Comment: An answer shouldn't explain the question. An answer should solve the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be wanting to extend `HTMLElement`. The proper way to do it is by adding your method to the `prototype` of `HTMLElement`.

For example (I didn't use your original function code because it's quite vague in what it tried to achieve):

```
HTMLElement.prototype.getMyWidth = function() {
    return this.clientWidth;
};
```

See [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement)

Comment: this is exactly how i want can you explain a bit please why we used prototype and how to recall this

Comment: And this is what most of us would try really hard to avoid, extending native constructors/prototypes.

Comment: @adeneo, I was pondering whether to cite the critics on this technique as well. However, from pure JS perspective (regardless of DOM and browsers) it's a better approach and hopefully would lead the OP in the correct path.

Comment: @nikoss, prototype is a basic subject in Javascript. Try to read more on the subject (for example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype)

Comment: @adeneo in this case to write a function which will return node and adding property right after this function is better e.g.
_("#elem").wide and Why we must avoid adding into native constructors

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice

Answer (score 1):

```
function ElementObj(element){
    this.element = element;
    this.width = this.element.offsetWidth;

    return this;
}
```

Now you can do:

```
var elem1 = new ElementObj(document.getElementById('div1'));
var elem2 = new ElementObj(document.getElementById('div2'));
```

Where elem1 returns object:

```
{
    element: DOMElement
    width: 100
}
```